# multererror unexpected field multiple files flutter and node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter, multer, multifile-uploader

Flutter form data

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
     "order_image": [
      for (var file in images)
        ...{
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(getImage(file).imageFile.path,
              filename: getImage(file).imageFile.path.split('/').last)
        }.toList()
    ],
  "user_name": "Jan"
    
  });
```

node js

```
router.post('/express-order', uploadFile.array(orderImageKeyName), postOrders);
```

multer middleware

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null,settings.ORDER_IMG_DIR);
  },
  
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {

    cb(null, `${Date.now()}-bezkoder-${file.originalname}`);

    
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from `Flutter` form data

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
     "order_image": [
      for (var file in images)
        ...{
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(getImage(file).imageFile.path,
              filename: getImage(file).imageFile.path.split('/').last)
        }.toList()
    ],
  "user_name": "Jan"
    
  });
```

change to

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    
  "user_name": "Jan"
    
});


formData.files.addAll([
    for (var file in images)
      ...{
        MapEntry(
            "order_image",
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(getImage(file).imageFile.path,
                filename: getImage(file).imageFile.path.split('/').last))
      }.toList()
  ]);
```

from node js
we need to mention count in `upload.array`

multer({ storage: storage }).array(orderImageKeyName, `10`)

final nodejs

```
router.post('/express-order', upld, postOrders);
```

change multer middle ware tooo

```
const util = require("util");

const upld = async(req, res, next) => {
   await util.promisify(uploadFile(req, res, next));
}

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null,settings.ORDER_IMG_DIR);
  },
  
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {

    if(file.originalname.length>10)
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}-bezkoder-${file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.length-10,file.originalname.length)}`);
    
    else
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}-bezkoder-${file.originalname}`);

    
  },
});
var uploadFiles = multer({ storage: storage }).array(orderImageKeyName, 10);
module.exports = uploadFiles;
```